# Java 8 flatMapped stream closed in try-with-resources block

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream, monads

I have two methods that return length's of strings in a list as follows;

```
    private Stream<Integer> method1(List<String> list) {
        try (final Stream<String> myStream = list.stream()) {
            return myStream.map(String::length);
        }
    }
```

and

```
    private Stream<Integer> method2(List<String> list) {
        try (final Stream<String> myStream = list.stream()) {
            return myStream.map(String::length).flatMap(Stream::of);
        }
    }
```

when I try to consume the resulting stream of either of the methods with;

```
    List<Integer> collect = method1(list).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
    List<Integer> collect = method2(list).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I get

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: source already consumed or closed
```

Now I'm aware that using a stream in a try-with-resources block is not common. But in my real code I'm using `Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Path.of(myPath))` in try-with-resources. And in the documentation of `Files.walk(..)` method it says

> This method must be used within a try-with-resources statement or similar control structure to ensure that the stream's open directories are closed promptly after the stream's operations have completed.

The code above is just an example to show the problem.

My question is why my streams are closed although I use `map` and `flatMap` to return a new stream. Am I wrong to expect that these two methods return new `Stream` instance hence only the `myStream` is closed but not the returned one from the `map` operation? I have a vague understanding of monads but do `map` and `flatMap` methods' behaviors mean `Stream` is not a real monad?

Comment: Don't use *try-with-resources* and let the caller handle the closing of streams

Comment: I'm using try-with-resources for my stream in my method. Then I expect this method to create another stream for method caller to consume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stream` would be closed once `try` block is completed.

Because `Stream<T>` extends `BaseStream<T, Stream<T>>` and `BaseStream` extends `AutoCloseable`

> why the Stream instance I created in the block is also closed

Because the new `Stream` instance created in the block is a chained nested 
 stream of `myStream` and would be closed immediately after `myStream` (outer stream) is closed. You can verify it with `onClose` as below,

```
privat Stream<Integer> method1(List<String> list) {
    try (final Stream<String> myStream = list.stream()) {
        Stream<Integer> integerStream = myStream.onClose(r)
                .map(String::length).onClose(r1);
        return integerStream;
    }
}
Runnable r = ()->{
    System.out.println("closed main stream...");
};
Runnable r1 = ()->{
    System.out.println("closed map stream...");
};
```

Comment: I'm aware that the stream in try-with-resources would be closed. I'm asking why the `Stream` instance I created in the block is also closed.

Comment: @Taha updated the answer. Rephrase your question with the above comment, I will vote for reopening the question.

Comment: I already did before that comment. Somehow I cannot mention your username.

Comment: @Taha there is only one stream. There are only different Stream instances to support fluent building like `stream.map(...).filter(...).distinct()`, whereas each time you chain an operation, you may get a new instance representing the stream, which invalidates the old ones. Since there is only one stream, there is only one "closed" state.

Comment: Hi guys I wanna ask about this case. In my program it will raise No file descriptors available when I do not use try with resources but when I do try with resources I got the problem with "source already consumed or closed". If I do like this solution will the "integerStream" raise No file descriptors available. Tks